# Local Linux server not accessible externally during an outgoing OpenVPN connection

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, openvpn, openwrt

I have a Debian Linux server which I use for file storage. It is in a local network with port forwarding configured in the router (openwrt). I sometimes connect the server to an OpenVPN server for different reasons, downloading files only accessible in certain regions being one.

I can access it just fine from outside the network using SSH, but as soon as I connect the server to OpenVPN all requests coming from the WAN side time out. Machines from within the local network can still access the server without any problems.

So what I am trying to achieve is for the server to still be accessible from an external connection despite being having a temporary OpenVPN connection.

I've been trying to understand what is happening by running tcpdump on both server and router (all interfaces), using the command below, but I still cannot find the request that times out in the resulting file...

```
tcpdump -i any -v -w capture.cap
```

My first guess was that the OpenVPN client does something to block incoming requests with a non-local origin, but then I thought I would have seen the request in the packet capture on the router at least... Incoming requests to other machines does work while the server has the OpenVPN connection active however, which would suggest the problem being on the server and not the router side at least.

So I'm at a bit of a loss, I fail to understand what is happening here. Any ideas?

Edit:
Output from netstat -r as suggested by Esa:

```
root@server1:~# netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.10.31.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.31.0      *               255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 tun0
amalthea.anonin 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.10.31.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, when an OpenVPN client is active, only network traffic to and from the OpenVPN server site will pass over the VPN, i.e. you only have new routes to the subnets on the remote side, while the *default gateway* stays local.

If all traffic goes through VPN, you may have these on your server configuration file:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

Remove them.

`tcpdump` is not the best way for investigating this. Instead, examine your *routing table* with `netstat -r`. There, look at destination `default` / `0.0.0.0`. That shouldn't be your VPN's gateway. Otherwise it causes just the problem you are facing.

Comment: Interesting. So what you're saying then is that the external requests actually reach the server, but when it responds to them it tries to do it through the vpn tunnel? How does that work though? I mean, the request comes in on eth0, so wouldn't it use the default gateway for eth0 to respond to the request, as opposed to the openvpn server which is on tun0?
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface

default         10.10.30.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0`